# Issue regards data in charts JS

Tags: charts, chart.js

I have an issue connected with my line chart created in CHARTS JS.
Everything is working correctly but on the line "X" I wanted to have a date and it looks like:

```
czas = date("dmy", strtotime($row["data"]));
```

But it looks e.g. today -> 1122019.

My idea was to create 1.12.2019, but when I change the date format for "d.m.y" it is not working. The Chart disappear.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

d.mm.yyyy is no date format Javascript can read. You have to provide a format JS can read. You find more information at about JS Date [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).